# Adding in a UpperCase function in a existing function?

Tags: javascript

I want to make sure the designations parameter in the designationLinks function, which would take an array, would always take in array with lowercase values. If it's uppercase, it should be lowercased before running through the newLinks variable. So both parameters like ["aaa", "ccc", "sss"] and ["AAA", "CCC", "SSS"] would both passing as arrays initially but be lowercased when running through the function. The key think here is I want the uppercase functionality to happen within the designationLinks function.

JS

```
 var designationLinks = function(themeData, designations) {

    var newLinks = designations.map(function(agentDesignations){
        return '<a class = "designation-box" data-toggle = "modal" data-target = "#'
            + agentDesignations + '-modal" data-value = '
            + agentDesignations + '>' + themeData[agentDesignations + "_name"] + '</a>';
    });
    return newLinks.join("\n");
};
```

Comment: Uhm, `designations.map( x => x.toLowerCase()).map(...`

Comment: `agentDesignations` - > `agentDesignations.toLowerCase()` (in inner func)

Comment: @adeneo: don't confuse noobs with methodical functions, unless you show how to bind...

Comment: or simply do this when calling the function: `var result = designationLinks(x,y.map(function(x){return x.tolowerCase()}));`

Comment: @adeneo Where in function can I write that? Can you show me?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/pscxtLt1/

Comment: @adeneo This is still failing when I pass capital letters in array through. Any suggestions?